# Des dialogues « au cordeau » : détails ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, synonymes, cinéma, théatre

Dans un texte on discute d'une série télévisée : « Des dialogues au cordeau [...] » nous dit-on. Au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cordeau) on dit qu'au figuré ça signifie « de manière régulière », le [*cordeau*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cordeau/19251?q=cordeau#19137) c'est la petite corde servant à tracer une ligne droite entre deux points ; au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cordeau) on trouve par extension « de façon nette et régulière, symétrique », ou ces références à la pêche et aux explosifs.

Quand on dit de dialogues qu'ils sont « au cordeau », que veut-on dire exactement, à quelle qualité réfère-t-on ? Peut-on préciser, est-ce un synonyme de l'état de ce qui a été *taillé au [couteau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couteau)*, est-ce *incisif*, *mordant*, ou plutôt d'un adverbe comme *régulièrement*, mais régulièrement *quoi* au juste, y a-t-il ellipse et de quoi ; cet emploi d'*au cordeau* est-il courant ?

Comment: [Article](https://www.lapresse.ca/arts/television/201810/16/01-5200551-roseanne-revient-sous-un-nouveau-nom-et-sans-roseanne.php) ayant inspiré la question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cette expression est tout sauf populaire et encore moins péjorante, au contraire.

Elle est usuelle... d'abord dans le milieu... du théatre puis dans celui du cinéma.

Son sens est absolument calqué sur le sens figuré de l'expression *tirer au cordeau* pour s'appliquer de manière logique aux... **tirades** des acteurs.

On rencontrera d'ailleurs (mais plus rarement) l'expression de *tirade au cordeau* sous la plume de certains critiques artistiques.

*dialogue / tirade au cordeau* sont des observations plutôt positives, on peut les rencontrer aussi dans des préfaces (Philipe Durant, Bernard Sarrut...)

EDIT suivant commentaire. Un dialogue *au cordeau* caractériserait alors un dialogue dans lequel les interlocuteurs vont droit au fait, ne s'encombrent pas de fioritures, ne tournent pas en rond autour du pot...

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme : Est-ce que l'adjectif *direct* / *Sans fioritures* ou encore *sans tourner en rond* t'éclaireraient plus ?

Comment: Je ne crois pas que "péjorante" s'utilise comme ça... (En fait le verbe "péjorer" n'existe pas vraiment.) On dit plutôt "péjorative".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : 1/ OK il n'est pas dans le DAF! Mais... rassure-moi... cela ne veut pas dire qu'il n'existe pas... hein? 2/ Tu le trouveras en tout cas utilisé, et en ce sens, dans de nombreux ouvrages de référence, en particulier dans les Cahiers de Linguistique Française (https://books.google.fr/books?id=kjNcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22p%C3%A9jorant%22&dq=%22p%C3%A9jorant%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOwPuO7Y3eAhXMfFAKHbrrDe8Q6AEIOzAD)... moi... ça me suffit pour dire que... il existe! ;-)

Comment: 1/ C'est quoi toutes ces ellipses ? C'est n'importe quoi et illisible. 2/ Si un mot n'est pas dans les dictionnaires et n'est pas utilisé couramment, alors non, il n'existe pas. Le fait que quelques auteurs inventent un néologisme et l'utilisent une fois ou deux ne fait pas que le mot devient du français correct.

Answer (score -3):

Tout d'abord je pense que c'est une façon très populaire d'exprimer la chose, trop populaire, qui la tourne quelque peu en dérision. Ce que ça doit communiquer, il me semble, c'est soit une qualité particulière du comportement des protagonistes dialoguant en cela qu'ils respectent scrupuleusement leurs interlocuteurs sans les couper, en reprenant méticuleusement tous les points qui ont été formulés, sans éclats de voix, etc., soit l'existence d'une organisation formelle du dialogue avec des règles, comme un temps de parole, l'obligation de répondre précisément à toute les questions, et possiblement quelques autres règles assez contraignantes, soit encore un concours des deux possibilités.

Je ne crois pas que l'emploi soit très courant (et ne souhaite pas le voir le devenir).

Comment: Ha mhé! Aucune dérision dans tout cela! Vraiment! Et, pas vraiment *populaire* non plus puisqu'au contraire appliquée par des locuteurs plutôt... spécialisés. (Cf autre contrib)

Comment: @aCOSwt Eh bien, ces locuteurs spécialisés passeront chez moi pour avoir des affinités pour des moyens   d'expression  populaires; ce n'a pas été une tradition  des intellectuels français de se référer aux rangées de choux pour formuler leurs pensées.

Comment: lol! Heureusement que les *intellectuels* n'écrivent pas de pièces de théatre... je crois que ce serait... ch... Après ton planteur de choux mérite-t-il ton dédain quand il ... rend hommage à Euclide ?

Comment: @aCOSwt En effet, non et je ne lui en porte aucun, c'est un bien long et humble hommage!

Comment: Reste que ca n'est absolument pas ou plus populaire à l'heure actuelle, sans être non plus réservée à l'élite...

Comment: @nonobstant Oui, le terme « structuré » capture l'idée mais je ne pense pas que j'insiste sur des extrêmes; le terme impliquerait selon moi une certaine rigueur de par une étiquette qui peut être plus ou moins sévère et pas nécessairement négative.  Il faut souligner que j'ai négligé une possibilité importante , (une autre réponse le suggère) : je ne considère pas le dialogue comme on l'entend au théâtre mais seulement le dialogue dans le sens du débat; il me semble maintenant qu'il ne pourrait s'agir que de la première possibilité, le terme « régulier » n'évoquant alors rien pour moi .

Comment: Merci, oui bien le texte faisait la critique d'une série et vous n'aviez pas le contexte exact. Normalement j'aurais présenté un extrait plus complet et la source mais je voulais sortir du contexte et voir si on avait une compréhension usuelle de ce cordeau-là. Je ne croyais pas nécessaire de devoir mentionner que je n'avais jamais entendu ça de ma vie. Par ailleurs je suis francophone et j'ai complété le lycée etc. et parfois avec le contexte on ne réussit pas vraiment à aller plus loin que les intuitions que j'ai déjà au départ. Ça devient la question de la part du contexte ds. le sens etc.